# Xcode compiler cannot find C++ 11 includes

Tags: xcode, c++11

I developed some classes in Visual Studio 2012 which make heavy use of C++11 features and also uses new std features like threads and mutex. The reason was to be platform independent. Trying to port the code to OSX the Xcode compiler 5.0 cannot open following includes:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
```

I already switch the build settings to C++11 and searched the usr/include path for the includes. Please do not suggest boost as I try to eliminate it from my projects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need both `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libc++`:

```
$ cat cpptest.cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>

int main() {
    return 0;
}

$ clang -o cpptest -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ cpptest.cpp
$ echo $?
0
```

Comment: Okay, I found that the project I am using is set to -std=gnu++11 and stdlib=libstdc++ (the compiler command line shows that) . But on the project page it is set as you recommend. Whats going on here.

Comment: @MartinSchlott So the correct options are showing in the left-most column?  Also please post the command line that Xcode is using to compile the source file.

Comment: Found it! Thanx for asking for the compiler command line :-). I am not used to Xcode compiler. On the Build Settings, I only checked the the project settings, not the target settings. The target settings differed from the project settings as they used the gnu stuff. I corrected that. Thx for the help.

Answer (score 6):

Give that you're using Xcode, you shouldn't need to specify explicit flags to `clang` or add build paths to `/usr/include`, as that is done for you by the IDE. What you need to do is open the project settings -> Build Settings and set **C++ Language Dialect** to **C++11** and the **C++ Standard Library** to **libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)**

Comment: You are right. The main problem was, that I was taking an existing project which was totally misconfingurated.