# Installing package on R, need C++11 support for OSX

Tags: r, macos, c++11

I'm trying to install `library(Boom)` for Bayesian Object Oriented Modeling and its dependencies `BoomSpikeSlab, bsts`. However, I always get the same response from `R`:

```
In file included from Models/Glm/MultinomialLogitModel.cpp:31:
In file included from     ../inst/include/Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/MLVS.hpp:25:
In file included from     ../inst/include/Models/Glm/PosteriorSamplers/MLVS_data_imputer.hpp:25:
../inst/include/Models/PosteriorSamplers/Imputer.hpp:30:10: fatal     error: 'future' file not found
#include <future>
     ^
 1 error generated.
 make: *** [Models/Glm/MultinomialLogitModel.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Boom’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/Boom’
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘Boom’ had non-zero exit status
 ERROR: dependency ‘Boom’ is not available for package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’
 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/BoomSpikeSlab’
Warning in install.packages :
 installation of package ‘BoomSpikeSlab’ had non-zero exit status
 ERROR: dependencies ‘BoomSpikeSlab’, ‘Boom’ are not available for     package ‘bsts’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/3.2/site-library/bsts’
  Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘bsts’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/s2/9wz53mrj0vqcpj9v3zjwx6q80000gn/T/RtmpvMmIug/downloaded_packages’
```

I thought that might be related to my problem
[pip cffi package installation failed on osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27740044/pip-cffi-package-installation-failed-on-osx)

so I tried :

```
xcode-select --install
```

which resulted in:

```
xcode-select: Error: unknown command option '--install'.

xcode-select: Report or change the path to the active
          Xcode installation for this machine.

Usage: xcode-select --print-path
       Prints the path of the active Xcode folder
  or: xcode-select --switch <xcode_path>
       Sets the path for the active Xcode folder
  or: xcode-select --version
       Prints the version of xcode-select
```

How can I install the `Boom`package?

I'm using `Mac OSX 10.8.5` with `Xcode version: 5.1.0`
`Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.6.0`

Comment: I just installed it with no problems. Is `install` documented as a permissible switch in `man xcode-select`?

Comment: Hi, no its not. Maybe because `Xcode 5.1.0`?

Comment: Do you have a C++11 compiler installed?  `std::future` is new.

Comment: I also had a similar missing library problem when I tried installing `imager` package. I installed `cimg-dev` and it worked. [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future) library was added in C++11 and in turns out [`Boom`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boom/index.html) package requires C++ 11. So it's surely a missing library problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a library problem, but a language version problem.  I am not familiar with OSX so I do not know how to select C++11 language version when R builds packages.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089293/xcode-compiler-cannot-find-c-11-includes

Comment: Perhaps the edit will help.  If it's not what you want, feel free to roll it back.

Comment: I `brew cimg` and use `clang++ -std=c++11`. Adding `cimg` doesnt change anything

Comment: @MatthewLundberg: Xcode has shipped with a version of `clang` which fully supports C++11 for about 5 years.  This is almost certainly due to the missing `--std=c++11` flag.

Comment: I'm still fighting "the Boom problem" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034316/r-package-boom-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 0):

Well, [Boom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boom/index.html) is on CRAN so it by that very construction *must work* with the default toolchain.

Do you have [BH](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BH/index.html) installed?   The corresponding clang version worked for years as we added *optional* C++11 support in [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel/code/rcpp.html) at least as early as March 2013 (when we added support for `Rcpp::plugin(cpp11)`.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thank you for that suggestion. I have installed `BH`. However, `install.packages("Boom")`results in the same output as depicted above

Comment: Yes, `dplyr`I can install. `clang++`is used. `Boom` uses `clang++ -std=c++11`.

Comment: Which is what I told you earlier: _It is on CRAN_ so it passed a pretty stringent buildability test.  If it fails on your end it is _your setup_ which I would look at first.

Comment: Until today I thought I have a rather standard setup, but 'Boom' fails to compile... Any ideas/suggestions where to look how my apparently nonstandard setup differs from the standard so that 'Boom' does not compile? ;) I looked around SO and www in general without success.

Comment: I asked a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36034316/r-package-boom-fails-to-install-on-ubuntu-linux