# package Boom not installing on PC

Tags: r, windows

I'm unable to install the `R` package `Boom` on Windows PC. I tried on two separate PCs and get the same error:

```
Warning: running command 'make -f "Makevars" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" CXX='$(CXX1X) $(CXX1XSTD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX1XFLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX1XPICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX1XLD)' SHLIB="Boom.dll" ' had status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Boom'
* removing 'C:/Users/nlc538/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/Boom'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\nlc538\Documents\R\win-library\3.2" C:\Users\nlc538\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpo3vflH/downloaded_packages/Boom_0.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘Boom’ had non-zero exit status
```

This is related to the question [Installing package on R, need C++11 support for OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858596/installing-package-on-r-need-c11-support-for-osx), however that was for installation on a Mac and was not fully answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem but solved it by installing the 'Boom'-package from a zip file downloaded from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Boom/index.html. Instead of installing 'Boom_0.3.tar.gz', using 'Boom_0.3.zip' worked for me.